# Adjective for a period of time that feels much longer than it actually is

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word for describing *a period of time that feels much longer than it actually is*?

To fill in the blanks below for example

> Only few days have passed but it feels like months. How ___ .
>
> The time we spent on the island has been ___ . It is as if we'd lived there for years.
>
> Reading the source code is quite a ___ task.

Comment: Do you have a preferred register? That is, would a slang term work, or are you specifically looking for something more formal? Also, do you specifically want an adjective?

Comment: You could use _slow motion_ in your context (although it doesn't exactly fit in your examples). Related excerpt from an article: "With lots of new stimuli our brains take longer to process the information so that the period of time feels longer. This would help to explain the “slow motion perception” often reported in the moments before an accident." - [_www.independent.co.uk_](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/why-does-time-last-forever-when-you-re-young-a7191476.html)

Comment: *slow-going*...

Comment: A single adjective to fit all your examples is *tedious*.

Comment: @ermanen that is a very interesting article. thanks!

Comment: @1006a anything would do! Just exploring for ideas. A single adjective would of course be the best.

Answer (score 3):

When time feels like it is passing slower than usual, we usually say that it is [dragging](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drag):

> 2 (of time) pass slowly and tediously.

*’the day dragged—eventually it was time for bed’*

I don’t think it’s quite the single word you were looking for, but in conjunction with “time” it can fill the blank in all your examples.

It does have fairly negative connotations; we often used *stretched* in more positive situations. E.g.:

> “The long summer days stretched out, so by the autumn it felt like we hadn’t been to school in years.”

Comment: This is perhaps as close as one can get. It addresses the subjective requirement.

Comment: There is also the more casual term [***draggy***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/draggy), to fulfill the OP's request for an adjective, though I don't know if it perfectly fits all the example blanks.

Answer (score 1):

The typical metaphor would be ***an eternity***. The other way, possibly *cliché*, is *[for] **what seemed like an eternity***.

Answer (score 0):

Glacial is frequently used in just this way.

"suggestive of the very slow movement of glaciers ·progress on the bill has been glacial"(MW)

Interestingly, there is a concept in fictional narrative that may also be useful. If a long segment of the text is devoted to a short period of the story, it is called deceleration. So a decelerated event has a short duration in time but extends for an inordinate amount of text compared to the normal event time/text length for the narrative. Narrative Fiction, Shlomith Rimmon-Kenan, Routledge.

In more general use, "The event decelerated as the week progressed."

The time we spent on the island has decelerated. It is as if we'd lived there for years.

Comment: This _actually is_ lengthy.

Comment: @edwin Seems, feels, as if . . .

Comment: 'Glacial' used metaphorically means 'extremely slow / taking ages' _not_ 'feeling much longer than it actually is'.

Comment: The history professor's two-hour class passed glacially. The history professor's two-hour class seemed to pass glacially. The new glacier formed lickety-split, uncharacteristically non-glacially.

Comment: The 'seems' needs to be **built into** the word. Read the question again. 'Glacial' is wrong.

Comment: "How was your weekend at your grandmother's?" "Glacial, man." "How was your weekend in the tropics?" "Cool, man."

Comment: **glacial**: [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/glacial): 1b. Extremely slow, like the movement of a glacier: _Work proceeded at a glacial pace._ // Collins: 6 very slow in progress: _a glacial pace_. // RHK Webster's: 5. happening or moving extremely slowly. //// [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/glacial): 3 extremely slow _The plot moves at a glacial pace._ //// [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/glacial): 1.2 Extremely slow (like the movement of a glacier) _an official described progress in the talks as glacial_.... ////

Comment: When a parents asks a child, 'How long did your homework take?' The child might answer, "It took forever." The parent and the child both know that it didn't take forever, but to the child that short amount of time seemed or felt like a very long time. Glacial is frequently used in the same way.

Comment: You have actual examples with references? And are you suggesting that 'glacial' is acceptable in  "Only few days have passed but it feels like months. How ___ ." / 

"The time we spent on the island has been ___ . It is as if we'd lived there for years." / 

"Reading the source code is quite a ___ task"?

Comment: 'Macnaghten and Urry [sociologists) provide the example of glacial time by which they mean time that is experienced as extremely slow and ponderous." Nature and Sociology by Tim Newton, page 48.

Comment: 'by which they mean' indicates a nonce usage. I see you haven't answered my second question. As I rather expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, studies of moral judgment move at a glacial pace relative to thespeed of neural processing.
He has a glacial pace doing his job.
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=glacial%20pace

Comment: Why does this necessarily mean other than 'very slowly'? Where is the 'feels much longer than it actually is' requirement? As I've said below, only 'dragging', which requires rephrasing anyway, denotes 'time dilation' ie the 'feels much longer than it actually is' requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Simple as it is, you could just use "slow" or any of its synonyms.
"How slow."
"has been slow"
"a slow task"

I'd argue that "time is slow" implies that the period of time seems longer than it actually is, since we're all aware that time isn't *literally* being slow (unless this is sci-fi, or something).